# Apache superset with mongoDB(NO SQL database)

Tags: sql, mongodb, apache-superset, apache-drill

I am using MongoDB. My task is to build Dashboard charts for the data. So, I am using Apache superset. I connected MongoDB to apache drill as it wont connect directly with superset. Then connected apache drill to Apachesueperset. My collection is nested. How can I process this nested data to get use for dashboard charts.My data looks as below

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6229d3cfdbfc81a8777e4821"
  },
  "jobs": [
    {
      "job_ID": {
        "$oid": "62289ded8079821eb24760e0"
      },
      "New": false,
      "Expired": false
    },
    {
      "job_ID": {
        "$oid": "6228a252fb4554dd5c48202a"
      },
      "New": true,
      "Expired": true
    },
    {
      "job_ID": {
        "$oid": "622af1c391b290d34701af9f"
      },
      "New": true,
      "Expired": false
    }
  ],
  "email": "mani2090996@ail.com"
}
```

I am querying in apache drill as follows

```
SELECT flat.fill FROM (SELECT FLATTEN(t.jobs) AS fill FROM mongo.recruitingdb.flatten.`Vendorjobs` t) flat WHERE flat.fill.New  = flase;
```

And i am getting  parsing error
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: Encountered "." at line 1, column 123.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots (where relevant information is cropped, by the way). Use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superset doesn't really handle nested data very well.  Drill does however, so you'll have to craft queries to produce columns that can be visualized.
Take a look here: https://drill.apache.org/docs/json-data-model/
and here: https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-complex-data-introduction/.

**UPDATE:**

Try the query below.  The `FROM` clause may not be exactly right, but you should get the idea from this.

Note that you can access maps in Drill in two ways:

- `tablename.mapname.field` OR
- `mapname['field']`

You can do this for any level of nesting.

```
SELECT mongoTable.jobs.job_ID.`$oid` AS job_ID,
mongoTable.jobs.`New` AS new,
mongoTable.jobs.`Expired` AS expired
FROM 
(
   SELECT flatten(jobs) AS jobs
   FROM mongo.recruitingdb.flatten.`Vendorjobs` AS t1
   WHERE t1.jobs.New = false
) AS mongoTable
```

Comment: thanks very helpful, but Kvgen function is working for nested value of simple type getting error while querying for deep nested.

Comment: Without seeing a sample of your data or the error message, I can't really help.

Comment: When I run the query by removing flatten from "FROM mongo.recruitingdb.flatten.`Vendorjobs` AS t1" I am getting null table  values.

Comment: Drill has a `FLATTEN()` function which is applied to lists.  There is no corresponding function for tables that I know of.  So when you remove `flatten` from the `FROM` clause, you are telling mongo to look at a different and possibly null document.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'd start with the inner subquery.  First get that working.   Once that is returning data, then you can wrap it as shown above to extract the individual fields.  Once you've done that, I'd suggest writing a view that hides all this which will make it easier to visualize.

Comment: Yes, I tried with flatten in From clause. But I am getting  schema error. No schema selected or found. So  I tried by removing flatten from  flatten, then I got the null values.

Comment: Flatten in the `FROM` clause will not do anything.  It sounds as if you are not selecting the correct schema.  Can you try a `SHOW DATABASES` query?